# Chrome Android elem.scrollIntoView() and overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

I've been using [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to replace old jQuery animate. It works perfectly everywhere I need but **Chrome Android**.

The target `element` is inside an `element` with an `overflow: auto;`

The behavior expected is to scroll inside the overflowed `element`, but on Android, it will **also scroll** the `documentElement` even if `html` and `body` have an `overflow: hidden;`

I've made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/romuleald/pen/NBPpbv) to reproduce the problem.

Did someone know a workaround?

Comment: I already have a light solution without `scrollIntoView` but it's sad https://codepen.io/romuleald/pen/NBqrJN

Comment: There's a bug filed in the Chrome bug-tracker https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=819314&q=scrollintoview&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: I have this problem too. It's 5 years since this question was asked and still no workaround keeping scrollIntoView.